# Force_ssl in ApplicationController, restrict all except for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to put `force_ssl` in the `ApplicationController` and pass in options to enforce ssl on all controllers except for certain controllers

Answer (score 0):

This solution is untested, but you should be able to do something like:

```
force_ssl except: ->{ INSECURE_CONTROLLERS.member? params[:controller] }
```

Answer (score 0):

`force_ssl` can be passed an optional array of actions, not specific controllers. If you're using `force_ssl` at the ApplicationController level, you can not override this inside its child controllers either. I'm pretty sure your only option is to declare `force_ssl` in every single controller except for the one that

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods/force_ssl